# Keras recursively train model

Tags: python, keras, prediction, lstm

I have a code that runs like this, more or less

```
for i in list:
train_lstm(attributes)
```

and then, further below, I have

```
def train_lstm(attributes):
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(100, 500,input_length=5))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
do the stuff
```

It's not really a bug, but my question is:

Since LSTM networks "remember", I suppose that it loses all its point if in every for-iteration I reset the network.
Should I then define the model outside the loop and reuse it?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(100, 500,input_length=5))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
for i in list:
    train_lst(attributes, model)
```

I'm using the network for time series prediction. Thanks

Comment: You are losing not only hidden states but also your weights. You are instantiating a completely new model - with all knowledgle lost. If you want to train the same model - but retrain it (not from the beginning - but with new data) use `model.reset_states()` at the beginning of your `for` loop and define one model for all loop runs.

Comment: So then better to use the second suggestion I've written, right?
Defining the model outside the for loop so that it is always reused. Thanks